# TV movie about old man washed up on shore, later he sets out to sea and washes up again as an old man

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv

I saw a TV show (70s or 80s) when I was a kid, where a man was lost at sea. Then near the end of the movie, he sets out again and ends up washing back up on the beach as an old man.

> Was there actually time travel involved? Or was he just lost that long?

He went into his past... then tried to return to his proper time... that's why he went back to the sea...

I think it may have been one of those quirky made-for-TV Sci-Fi shows that got me to love the genre.

---

It is not [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dalmb2bljE8) from *Inception* though that is similar.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that this is episode number eight from [Quinn Martin's Tales of the Unexpected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinn_Martin%27s_Tales_of_the_Unexpected), a short-lived anthology television series from 1977. Below is the episode's Wikipedia synopsis:

> United States Navy officer John Kelty is too busy with his career and his hobby–recreational boating–to pay attention to his wife and young son.  On June 3, 1952, he unwittingly pilots his boat through a time warp during a severe storm in the Bermuda Triangle and finds himself transported 25 years into the future to 1977.  He discovers that his wife is happily remarried–to a man who obviously cherishes her–and that his son has become a successful cardiologist who is making the same mistake he did by ignoring his own family, a mistake Kelty now believes ruined his own life.  Not letting his son know his real identity, Kelty befriends him and urges him to spend more time with his own wife and children.  Eventually, the elder Kelty goes back to sea to try to return to 1952 and correct his mistake by paying more attention to his wife and son, but his aged body is found washed ashore in 1977 after he drowns in the attempt.